# Which parser: SAX, DOM or xpath?

Tags: java, xml

I have xml on which I run queries as stated below. Which parser (sax or DOM or xpath) is best to retrieve query node by id?

Can you please explain me this with some sample code so that this will help me a lot?

I want to write a generic class which reads queries by id and passes parameters to it. What is the best way to return values after we executing queries since every query may return a different set of values?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queries>
    <query id="getUserByName">
        select * from users where name=?
    </query>
    <query id="getUserByEmail">
        select * from users where email=?
    </query>
</queries>
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758882/xml-parsing-using-java-with-getting-element-values-and-attribute-values

Comment: if you want to store sql queries in xml why not use mybatis? you wouldn't have to write the query-retrieval code, your jdbc code would go away, and you'd get features like caching for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It mainly depends on use case.

If generally talking, `SAX Parser` is good for parsing large file and `dom parser` for alternates.

The reason is `dom parser` ended up taking enough memory while parsing large file/input stream.

In my opinion, it needs to have some extent of experience to best utilize Sax Parser. Comparatively dom parsing is easier to learn and use.

Alternatively Apaches [commons-digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) can be alternative suggestion, if use case permits which  is easier compare to sax and uses sax internally.

And `xpath` is not a parser.

---

For your case, you do not need a parser. I think you are looking for xpath to retrieve sql queries using `xpath`.

If you need to generate a new xml for your simple `xml` you can do that manually. I can't suggest any better alternative right now.

Comment: Hi! Is this answer still up-to-date in 2019? Any new actor appeared?

Answer (score 3):

Better in order of usability and programmer productivity: SAX is worst, XPath is best.

Better in terms of saving machine cycles: SAX is best, XPath is worst.

So it depends whether your programmers cost more than your computers. Usually they do.

Answer (score 3):

If your really putting SQL into XML and then executing I would use MyBatis.

If you don't want to use MyBatis you should use JAXB and load the entire XML as a List of query objects because you don't want to reparse XML for every query. Let me show you how easy it is with JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "queries")
public class Queries {
  @XmlElement(name = "query")
  public List<Query> queries;
}

public Query {
  @XmlAttribute
  public String id;
  @XmlValue
  public String sql;
}

Queries queries = JAXB.unmarshal(file, Queries.class);
```

The above is not tested but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, XPath is not a query, but [a query language for selecting nodes from an XML document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

The main difference between SaX and DOM is that DOM will load all of your document into a memory structure. For small XML documents, you won't run into much trouble, but for a large XML document, memory usage may become an issue. SaX on the other hand will process your XML document in a streaming fashion, so in the end there is no object model representing the whole of your document. Instead you will need to keep track of the data you encountered in your document yourself.

For this case, my choice would be to use SaX and keep track of all queries in the document, for example in a `Map<String, String>` (where the key is the query ID and the value is the query itself).

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan must have resisted the urge to tell him to use JAXB :)

Answer (score 1):

The DOM specification defines a tree-based approach to navigating an XML document
The SAX specification defines an event-based approach whereby parsers scan through XML data, calling handler functions whenever certain parts of the document 
The strength of the SAX specification is that it can scan and parse gigabytes worth of XML documents without hitting resource limits

Answer (score 0):

**Sax parser** will be ideal for your case.I have written a blog post about [Sax parsing](http://sanjayacl.blogspot.com/2010/12/sax-parsera-simple-way-to-access-xml.html)

and another blog post on [how to choose a xml parser](http://sanjayacl.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-choose-xml-parser.html)

hope these will help you.